# Jackson One-to-One serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, cycle, bidirectional-relation

I am looking for a way in Jackson to allow serialization of a relationship depending on the root element.  For example, I have a relationship that is not a true parent/child.  Both entities can be queried.

```
Address {
    @JsonBackReference
    Company company;
    String line1;
    String city;
    String state;
    String zip;
    String country;
}

Company {
    Address mainAddress;

    List<Address> locations;
    String name;
}
```

The JsonBackReference makes it so there is no circular reference when serializing to json.  However, this also causes me to not know the company of an address.  If I am listing companies then the addresses come back and everything is good.  But if I am listing addresses I would want to see the company be serialized.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jackson's `@JsonTypeInfo` for serializing and deserializing. Please look at [Jackson's documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for more details. Try to avoid `1.9.8` version if you have static inner classes (This has a bug and leads to StackOverflowError).

Comment: Can you expand on this a little?  I'm not trying to solve which implementation is deserialized with this example.  When serializing an Address I want it's clients, but not the clients addresses.  And when I'm deserializing a Client I want it's address, but not the address' client.